# IOS: rotate an uiimageview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, rotation

in my app I have an imageview, its name is arrow and I rotate it of 180 degrees in this way:

```
arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

it work fine, but now I want that this imageview return in the original position; what's the value taht I should set to obtain it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make it return to it's original position, just do this:

```
arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
```

In degrees, 0 radians is 0 degrees, so it should return to its original position.

Answer (score 10):

Try setting the `transform` property back to the identity matrix. i.e. `CGAffineTransformIdentity`

Answer (score 0):

Swift3:

```
arrow.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation);
```

where *rotation* is the angle to rotate in radians.